# LibGDX destroy object when not used

Tags: libgdx, gameobject, objects

I am developing a game where objects move in the screen. My object is instantiated in Y = 0 and I want to destroy this object when it goes under the screen Height. 
So if (positionY >= ScreenHeight) I have to destroy this object to clean my game and prevent "lag".

How to do this? I have a dispose method (this.dispose) but it cause the dispose of the app and I want destroy only the object.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good idea to dispose/destroy your objects unless you want to change your screen (for example moving from menu to game level ) because when your are disposing/destroying objects , garbage collector is called ,so it's better to store your dead objects in memory instead of destroying them.

First off all read this article https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Memory-management specially **Object pooling**.

Pooling objects allow you to reusing your dead objects instead of recreating them.For example in your case you have several ways to reuse your dead object like this

```
if(myObject.getY>=screenHeight)
   myObject.setY(0);
```

Comment: I'll wait for others answer but maybe yours is the best

Comment: Unless you are creating thousands of objects, say to simulate rain, a pool might be more complexity than you need, in which case a simple array of objects should suffice.

Comment: Yes of course there are different ways in different situations but important thing is avoid destroying objects